# Running chrome in a server

Tags: php, google-chrome, centos

I have a CENTOS 7 server and I need to open a certain website once at every minute. I cant just request the main page using file_get_contents or an ajax call. No, I need to trully open the website in the Chrome browser, render all the scripts, set all cookies that those scripts will set, download all images... and after 30 seconds I need to close the page. I am creating a trully uptime service that renders all website and generates a report of everything that was downloaded, was working, was offline...

I mean, I really need to open the website in Chrome. The problem is this: in my Centos 7 server it probably does not have a screen, so how is it possible to me run chrome as if I were in front of the screen?

Comment: meybe it can help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/34687/is-there-a-text-mode-browser-which-supports-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think you need http://phantomjs.org/ Its a headless chrome browser and it can be run from servers. You can also set resolution for the "browser". For your task you can write a js file to be passed on opening the URL and after 30 seconds do a print screen.